# Effect of the location of igniter in starting liquid rocket engine

Tags: rockets, propulsion, liquid-fuel, spacecraft-development, ignition

What will be the effect of off axis igniter, say a Spark igniter has to be used along with a pintle? Will the igniter being off axis have any effect on engine start?

Also, will an off-center igniter be capable of damaging a un-started engine’s wall?(read as cooling is not flowing in the regenerative channels)